# Control if a new file incoming in a folder with "comm"

Tags: shell, command-line, ksh

I'm using a comm in a infinite cycle for view if a new file incoming in a folder, but i not have difference from 2 files but for example if incominig file "a" i view in output:

```
a a.out a.txt b.txt test.cpp testshell.sh
    a.out a.txt b.txt test.cpp testshell.sh
```

my Code is this:

```
#! /bin/ksh
ls1=$(ls);
echo $ls1 > a.txt;

 while [[ 1 > 0 ]] ; do
    ls2=$(ls);
    echo $ls2 > b.txt;
    #cat b.txt;
    #sort b.txt > b.txt;
    #diff -u a.txt b.txt;
    #diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y a.txt b.txt
    comm -3 a.txt b.txt;
    printf "\n";
    ls1=$ls2;
    echo $ls1 > a.txt;
    #cat a.txt;
    #sleep 2;
    #sort a.txt > a.txt;
 done
```

THANKS

Comment: When you echo your variables into the files, they need to be double quoted to reserve newlines - eg `echo "$ls1" > a.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/ksh

set -vx

PreCycle="$( ls -1 )"

while true
 do
   ThisCycle="$( ls -1 )"

   echo "${PreCycle}${ThisCycle}" | uniq

   PreCycle="${ThisCycle}"

   sleep 10
 done
```

give add and removed difference but without use of file. Could directly give new file same way but `uniq -f 1` failed (don't understand why) when used on list prefixed by `+` and `-` depending of source